# How to calculate the maximum number of independent pairing outcomes in a set based on which object in a pair is larger than the other

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the maximum number of independent pairing outcomes in a set based on which object in a pair is larger than the other. For example, in a small set of 6 objects A, B, C, D, E and F, it is clear that the worst case minimum number of independent pairing outcomes is 5 because if A>B and B>C and C>D and D>E and E>F then it can be deduced that A>C and A>D, etc all the way to D>F. So the minimum number of independent outcomes is 5 which is always N-1 with N being the # of objects in the set. But what is the maximum possible # of outcomes? For example when A>B but B<C and etc... Need an equation because my set is large and cannot do it by hand. Thanks. I saw somewhere which I can no longer find that it may be log(N!) with base 2. But not sure if that is correct.

Comment: There is no possible equality, eg A = B ? And if equality is possible, how is it treated in the pairing ?

Comment: Can you explain the problem differently?  As I read it, the answer would always be $n-1$, so what am I missing?  Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: You'd have to clarify further. My guess is that you want [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A001855).